# Chat flag handling options are ambiguous

Tags: feature-request, flags, chat, chat-flags

Recently, I saw a chat flag message pop up. The dialog looks like this:

[image: This message was flagged as spam/offensive by $n users: ... (valid) (invalid)(not sure)]

It presents 3 options to handle the flag: <kbd>valid</kbd>, <kbd>invalid</kbd>, <kbd>not sure</kbd>. These options are ambiguous.

Does "valid" mean "this flag is valid" or "this message is valid"? [I was told it means that the flag is valid](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/conversation/chat-flags). Regardless, it is ambiguous and should be changed to resolve the ambiguity.

Here are a couple ways it could be fixed:

> This message was flagged as spam/offensive by $n user(s):
>   ...
>   This flag is:
>   <kbd>valid</kbd> <kbd>invalid</kbd> <kbd>not sure</kbd>

> This message was flagged as spam/offensive by $n user(s):
>   ...
>   <kbd>spam/offensive</kbd> <kbd>okay</kbd> <kbd>not sure</kbd>

Comment: @animuson Is this really not a bug? I usually consider user-experience issues to be bugs.